# How to embed google search console anlytics reports into website using javascript?

Tags: javascript, embed, google-analytics-api, google-search-console

I want to embed the google search console results into my website.
I have already done with google analytics embed according to following API.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/

Is there any embed api for search console analytics report?
or any other javascript functionality which will fulfill my requirements

I want to display following report from google search console into my web-site
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.. i see this tutorial --> https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/basic-dashboard/

I think that can help you

Comment: Thank for your reply. That embed api is used for google analytics. I want to embed google search console analytics.